# ytapiquotarequest form has reCAPTCHA V1

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I wanted to fill:
https://services.google.com/fb/forms/ytapiquotarequest/

However it's protected by reCAPTCHA V1. Lot's of lols and rotfls but putting them aside - it would be nice to fill the form.

Typing: `reCAPTCHA V1 IS SHUTDOWN` and `V1` didn't do much.

Any idea how to get past it?

Answer (score 0):

A workaround has been provided for this in the [What happens to reCAPTCHA v1?](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#what-happens-to-recaptcha-v1)

> please upgrade to reCAPTCHA v2 immediately. We no longer support
>   reCAPTCHA v1. Any calls to the v1 API will not work after March 31,
>   2018. Please [register a new key](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin#list) and upgrade to v2.

Comment: Dude, it's not my webpage I can't upgrade it.

Comment: Ask the guy who owns the webpage, what you doin with it if it's not yours?

Comment: Well, the web-page belongs to Google itself I believe.
I'm trying to send the form.
Good guy Google said that there is no way of contacting them but they do go through youtube-api tags on Stack Overflow.

Is there anything I could have done better given the circumstances?